# How can canvas coordinates be converted into tile coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, mouse-coordinates

So I have a canvas with an isometric tile map drawn on it, which looks perfect.

In the event listener at the bottom of the script, I grab the cursor's coordinates inside the canvas. How could I find out which tile the cursor is hovering over?

```
var cs = document.getElementById('board');

var c = cs.getContext("2d")
var gridWidth=100
var gridHeight=50
var tilesX = 12, tilesY = 12;
var spriteWidth=gridWidth
var spriteHeight=img.height/img.width*gridWidth
cs.width = window.innerWidth //spriteWidth*10
cs.height = window.innerHeight //spriteHeight*10
var ox = cs.width/2-spriteWidth/2
var oy = (tilesY * gridHeight) / 2

window.onresize=function(){
cs.width = window.innerWidth //spriteWidth*10
cs.height = window.innerHeight //spriteHeight*10
ox = cs.width/2-spriteWidth/2
oy = (tilesY * gridHeight) / 2
draw()
}

draw();


function renderImage(x, y) {
c.drawImage(img, ox + (x - y) * spriteWidth/2, oy + (y + x) * gridHeight/2-(spriteHeight-gridHeight),spriteWidth,spriteHeight)
}

function draw(){
for(var x = 0; x < tilesX; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < tilesY; y++) {
        renderImage(x,y)
    }
}
}

cs.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
var x = evt.clientX,
y = evt.clientY;
console.log('Mouse position: ' + x + ',' + y);
}, false);
```

Sorry for pasting such lengthy code, but all of it is there just to lay the isometric grid.

EDIT: Also, how could I get the top left coordinates of the tile image to relay it?

Comment: This was an answer I had for someone doing a regular 32x32 grid, but maybe you can get an idea for isometric? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615605/where-in-the-grid-the-tile-belongs/23615674?noredirect=1#comment36256591_23615674 -- it uses the modulo (%). I have no knowledge of iso grids, so I can't be further help, unfortunately.

Comment: You said elsewhere 'none of this work', so do not accept the answer and/or ask, @markE has both knowledge and kindness. You might want to have a close view at my post here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73859/adapting-tilemap-algorithm-to-support-isometric-tilemap/73874#73874 since the result is fine and you can configure it easily. On your way you might have to dig for what is a transformation matrix, and other things. Last (commented) code is here http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/zF2w8/

Comment: Thank you @GameAlchemist. Sorry for confusing people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've arranged your tiles where the leftmost column and topmost row are zero:

```
var column = parseInt(mouseX / tileWidth);

var row = parseInt(mouseY / tileHeight);
```

BTW,  if you eventually move your canvas off the top-left of the page then you must adjust your mouse coordinates by the canvas offset.

Here's an example of how to calculate mouse position:

```
// references to the canvas element and its context

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// get the offset position of the canvas on the web page

var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX=BB.left;
var offsetY=BB.top;

// listen for mousedown events

canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;

function handleMousedown(e){

     // tell the browser we will handle this event

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

     // calculate the mouse position

     var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
     var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;

}
```

Comment: So would I just do `+ oy` to add the offset?

Comment: I added to my answer with an example of how to calculate mouse position based on the canvas position within the web page.